# Python-side defaults are not invoked for each row individually when using a multivalued insert for Declarative-based models

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm using `sqlalchemy==1.1.4`. And I completely got stuck trying to execute multivalued `insert` for model inherited from `DeclarativeMeta` class. 
I have next declaration:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class SomeClass(Base):
    id = sa.Column(sa.String(length=64), primary_key=True,
               default=lambda: str(uuid4()))
    is_active = sa.Column(sa.Boolean, default=True)
    service_id = sa.Column(sa.String(length=100), nullable=False)
    order = sa.Column(sa.SmallInteger, default=0)
```

when I try multivalued insert like:

```
con.execute(
    sa.insert(SomeClass).values([
        {SomeClass.service_id: '12'},
        {SomeClass.service_id: '34'},
    ])
)
```

It throws

```
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: INSERT value for column SomeClass.service_id is
  explicitly rendered as a boundparameter in the VALUES clause; a
  Python-side value or SQL expression is required
```

According to Michael Bayer's post [link](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/migration_10.html#python-side-defaults-invoked-for-each-row-invidually-when-using-a-multivalued-insert) my code seemed to be correct by anyway, but it's even not compiled to sql expression. Though the next works perfectly:

```
con.execute(
    sa.insert(SomeClass).values([
        {SomeClass.service_id.key: '12'},
        {SomeClass.service_id.key: '34'},
    ])
)
```

Anybody knows what's the heck?)

Comment: That has nothing to do with default values. [`.values()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ValuesBase.values) takes a column *name* to value dict. Using the column expression seems to work for the single row case, but does not appear to be documented.

Comment: Yep, the problem is that every mention of [.values()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ValuesBase.values) is documented reflecting only string format of _column_name_ usage for multi rows, but no info about passing a list of dicts with keys like [Column](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column) or [InstrumentedAttribute](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html?highlight=instrumentedattribute#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute)

Answer (score 8):

That error should only occur if the list of elements you're passing to `insert.values()` contains inconsistent keys, Which means you may have a list like : `[{'name': 'foo', code:'foo'}, {'name': 'bar'}]`